# Are query plans stored per database?

Tags: sql-server

We have a multi-tenant environment with several hundred databases that are mostly identical schema-wise but I'm worried that a query plan may be the fastest for one database but not another.  For example, if we have one database that doesn't have a lot of data and you run a query that is deemed to be fast enough to do a scan across all rows and saves that plan but then if you run the same query against a much large database will it generate/save it's own plan or use the one created against the much smaller database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

When you have multiple instance of a database, they have the same schema, BUT each database different number records and statistics and ....
So it makes sense, SQL Server keeps execution plans per database.

Note: "storing" doesn't mean SQL Server, writes the query plans in database. They are stored in cache while SQL Server service is running and it has enough memory and the plan still need to be kept in cache for later use.

Comment: SQL Server may *calculate* execution plans for each database, but I find it highly unlikely that they're *stored*. Can you provide a link to official documentation that indicates they are?

Comment: SQL Server stores execution plans in system tables which are stored in each database separately. let me find a reference. Why do you think they are not stored?

Comment: They are stored in cache. Plain and simple. Any documentation you read about execution plans discusses storing them in cache.

Comment: @Sean: In cache doesn't equate to *stored* to me, as the cache is not persistent.

Comment: @KenWhite if we are splitting hairs on verbiage FLICKER never used the word "store". The answer here says "keeps execution plans per database". And most of the documentation and article on the topic actually states that it stores the execution plans in cache.

Comment: @Sean: The question asks *Are query plans stored?*, to which FLICKER replied *Yes!*. And we are splitting hairs here, because this site is for technically accurate answers. Stored does not typically mean *placed in the cache*, because that storage is not persistent between runs.

Comment: Tanks @SeanLange, how ever i mentioned in my comment that SQL stores the in system tables, I knew they are not stored as restarting the service, clears the cache. I don't know why I said that. Anyway, I explain the word "store" to not misleading anyone.

Comment: Thank you.  "Storing" was a poor choice of words, I get that they are cached.